STM32 MCU doesn't reset after flash
I'm using STM32CubeProgrammer to flash an MCU.
But after flash completes, to reset and run the MCU I have to interact with NRST pin by a push button.
Is there a way that right after the flash the MCU starts a reset automatically?

Through which interface you are uploading? USB/DFU, UART, or by using some JTAG/SWD adapter?

SWD using st-link V3

Under the Erasing & Programming tab, you have to enable the 'Run after programming' option.

Source: UM2237, page 28

It would be a great solution but my experience also is that for some reason it does not really go to run code after programming so I never used it or have tried it since. May depend on through which interface you upload the firmware.

@Justme If the GUI fails, I would try the command line interface (STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe). It gives you better control. Check out the --start and -rst commands.

The answer worked for me. But you need to click Start Programming instead of Download.

Thanks for the feedback
